# Prevent the action of a js plugin already launched

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Context :

I'm using jQuery plugin [stickyScroll](https://github.com/rickharris/StickyScroll) so when I'm in on a specific page the side bar comme along with the user that scroll.

[image]

**However I need to cancel that when the user goes to small screen size.**

[image]

I've tried to override the style but the plugin is stronger than a classic `!important`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() >= 991){
        $('.index2').stickyScroll({ container: '.containerIndex2' });
    }else{
        $('.sticy-active').style('top','0 !important');
    }
})
```

I've tough of using `return` too but I don't know how to said that it should return this specific function.

**So is there a way either to force a style more than with !important or to cancel a function action ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
if($(window).width() < 991){
  $('.index2').stickyScroll('reset');
}
```

The author is however [warning that his plugin is not performing well](https://github.com/rickharris/stickyscroll)

Comment: God damn me ! Thank you !!

Comment: But indeed it's completly buggy, triggering only if I resize it under 991px and I go over it and then back to 991 not working at all..
Do you know an other plugin that could answer the purpose ?

Comment: Sorry not off the top of my head. Search for responsive sticky

Answer (score 2):

you just need to do a reset function , it have on it document !

```
window.resize(resetSticky);
function resetSticy(){
if(window.innerWidth < 768)
  $('selector').stickyScroll('reset')
else
  $('selector').stickyScroll()
}
```

in this case you turning it on and off , based on user re-sizing or view port !
if you don't call it on document.ready it will only execute only when you resize your browser so you must do this .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
resetSticky();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "style" parameter to "css",

```
 $('.sticy-active').css('top','0 !important');
```

The most recent !important should get priority over previous uses.

Failing that, try removing the absolute positioning of the box as well (revert to position: relative; or position: fixed;)

Comment: Did you try changing the positioning to relative or fixed too?

Comment: Yep none of that is working the plugin overwrite it anyway :s

Comment: Ok - try setting it to display none to hide it entirely (with !important)